# Add an Up button on top of an Activity shown as a Dialog

Tags: android

To start an activity as a dialog, I have defined in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

This dialog show a title on top. ¿Is there a way to add a Up button (The one with shape "<" ) to dismiss the dialog, placed to the left of, or replacing, the title?

Comment: got any (visible) examples of that? Do you need to have an actionbar on the dialog?

Comment: do you mean by "<" button the back button in the action bar?

Comment: Can you be little clear with your dialog design?
To create a dialog without title you just need to call
`dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` before    your setContentView of dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare `Activity` with `ActionBar` and back button
 then apply in theme in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```